# How to return more specific HTTP code (like 401.X)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891/en-us) is an article about some extended HTTP codes:

> IIS 7.0, IIS 7.5, and IIS 8.0 define several HTTP status codes that
>   indicate a more specific cause of a 401 error. The following specific
>   HTTP status codes are displayed in the client browser but are not
>   displayed in the IIS log:
>
> - 401.1 - Logon failed.
> - 401.2 - Logon failed due to server configuration.
> - 401.3 - Unauthorized due to ACL on resource.
> - 401.4 - Authorization failed by filter.
> - 401.5 - Authorization failed by ISAPI/CGI application.

I need some custom extended HTTP codes like these:

> - 401.10 - User not found
> - 401.11 - User password mismatch
> - 401.12 - User account is locked
> - 401.13 - User account is expired
> - ...

How to return these extended 401 error codes from .NET MVC application?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want? You have asked if you can "return these", which mismatches with the accepted answer, as the answer by CodeCaster points out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your action method you set the status codes manually:

```
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.SubStatusCode = 10;
```

Additionally, you can use the HttpStatusCode enumeration in System.Net:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
```

Answer (score 9):

> How to return these extended 401 error codes from .NET MVC application?

You cannot return them from your application in the sense that the user will receive them, as HTTP does not support substatus codes.

They are used only for IIS logging and tracing, only the "major" status code is returned.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Response.StatusCode` and `Response.SubStatusCode`